# tmux: switch pane without losing current zoom state

Tags: tmux

Is there a way to configure tmux to maintain its current zoomed/not zoomed state when switching panes? I can add a keybinding to automatically zoom after switching pane as follows:

bind-key -n C-l select-pane -t :.+\;  resize-pane -Z

However this will zoom the new pane even if I was not previously zoomed. I would like to use the same keybinding to switch pane whether currently zoomed or not zoomed, and preserve the zoomed/not zoomed state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your version of tmux you can try this binding:

```
bind-key -n C-l if-shell -F "#{window_zoomed_flag}"  'select-pane -t :.+; resize-pane -Z'     'select-pane -t :.+'
```

This worked for me on tmux 2.2. `if-shell -F` does not run a shell command but just expands the `window_zoomed_flag` to 0 or 1, and runs the first or second command sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the command! This introduces a new top-level shortcut `C-l` (that is, no need to use the prefix `C-b`). But I wanted to keep the zoom when I toggle to the last selected pane (default `C-b`+`;`). So I developed the following top-level binding to use Alt/Meta+; to toggle to last selected pane without losing the zoom status.

`bind-key -n "M-;" if-shell -F "#{window_zoomed_flag}"  'select-pane -t :.!; resize-pane -Z'     'select-pane -t :.!'`